# Global variable in userforms does not work

Tags: excel, global-variables, userform, vba

I am creating userforms. Userforms are pretty connected to each other - use informations one from another. So... I thought about creating few global variables to make my life easier:

```
Public nazwa_arkusza As String
Public skoroszyt As Workbooks
Public arkusz As Worksheet
```

They are wrote in Useform **Klient_kraj**. **Edytuj** is `Combobox` within **Klient_kraj** Userform. I want to execute **arkusz** variable in different userform, but I get run-time error: "Object does not support this method"

```
Private Sub but_next_Click()

Dim Faktura As Range, faktury_range As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = Klient_kraj.skoroszyt.arkusz.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'error line

Set faktury_range = skoroszyt.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

(...)

end sub
```

.

```
Private Sub edytuj_Click()

Dim nazwa As String

nazwa_arkusza = kraj.List(kraj.ListIndex, 1) & " " & Mid(okres1.Value, 4, 2) & Mid(okres2.Value, 3, 3)

nazwa = "C:\1\" & klient.Text & ".xlsx"


'Jeżeli kraj nie wybrany = msgbox
If kraj.Value = "" Then

MsgBox ("Nie wybrałeś kraju")
Exit Sub:

Else

    If okres1.Value = "" Or okres2.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Nie wybrałeś okresu rozliczeniowego")
    Exit Sub:
    End If

End If


'Jeżeli nie ma pliku - utwórz nowy
If Dir(nazwa) = "" Then
    Workbooks.Add(1).SaveAs Filename:="C:\1\" & klient.Text, FileFormat:=51
    Worksheets(1).Name = nazwa_arkusza

Else

'Jeżeli nie jest otwarty - otwórz
    On Error GoTo niema_pliku:
    If GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Workbooks(Klient_kraj.klient.Text & ".xlsx") Is Nothing Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\1\" & klient.Text & ".xlsx"

    Else
    Workbooks(Klient_kraj.klient.Text).Activate

    End If

End If

Set skoroszyt = Workbooks(Klient_kraj.klient.Text & ".xlsx")

'Jeżeli arkusz nie istnieje - utwórz; istnieje - aktywuj
On Error GoTo niema_arkusza:
If skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Name = "" Then

Else
skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Activate

End If

On Error GoTo 0
Set arkusz = Sheets(nazwa_arkusza)
Application.Windows(klient.Text & ".xlsx").Visible = False
Faktura.Show

niema_pliku:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
Resume Next
End If

niema_arkusza:
If Err.Number = 9 Then
skoroszyt.Worksheets.Add.Name = nazwa_arkusza
skoroszyt.Worksheets(nazwa_arkusza).Activate
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

This variable will also be used in different userform.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `arkusz` is a `Worksheet` object: `arkusz As Worksheet`. What do you mean by `I want to execute arkusz variable in different userform`? How're you going to "execute worksheet" on different forms?

Comment: Public variable defined on userform becomes the property of Userform. In order to access them throughtout the project you need to define the variables in module.

Comment: Where exactly is the error being thrown?

Comment: @simoco 1st userform (if needed) creates new file and (if needed) creates new worksheet. During the use of userform worksheet used will be changed multiple times so it's important for me to know which one is actually used. So "execute" is little misleading term.

Comment: @Santosh well I can access variable **skoroszyt** all I need to do is add name of userforum before the variable. So far it's ok but maybe you are right I should move it to module.

Comment: @roryap, please read my question I provided that information.

Comment: @lowak As said above the variables are now property of Userform and can be accessed via `Objectname.Property` or other way is to move them to standard module.

Comment: @Santosh, ok correct me if I am wrong. There is hierarchy in VBA. Application -> Workbooks -> Worksheets etc... Having that in mind if I access variable via `Klient_kraj.skoroszyt` I should be able to also access another variable, in other words: `Klient_kraj.skoroszyt.arkusz`. But it does not work.

Comment: @Santosh, the thing is I want to preserve Workbooks().Worksheets() syntax. When I use `Klient_kraj.arkusz` it looses Workbooks() part. It's important for me, because workbook I am working on is hidden and I want to be 100% sure that data will be saved there.

Comment: `Public skoroszyt As Workbooks
Public arkusz As Worksheet` both are defined on userform and are the properties of Userform.

Comment: @Santosh, Ok I understand I should move it to module. Is this the only way to access it like: `skoroszyt.arkusz` ?

Comment: I moved declaration of public variables to module now it works better but still I cannot do `skoroszyt.arkusz`. What is wrong?

Comment: `skoroszyt` refers to Workbooks and `arkusz` refers to  Worksheet . You need to set them before you access them this way `skoroszyt.arkusz` . Make sure this objects are not nothing.

Comment: @Santosh Objects are surely "something". You can look at my code: firstly `Edytuj_Click()` is executed and later on, from another userform is executed `but_next_Click()`. It looks like skoroszyt does not see `arkusz`

Comment: @Santosh, any ideas what is wrong?